# Filter from list - Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, filter

I was wondering if someone can help me with a homework problem.

Write a function, func(a,x), that takes an array, a, x being both numbers, and returns an array containing only the values of a that are greater than or equal to x

I have

```
def threshold(a,x):
    for i in a:
        if i>x: print i
```

But this is the wrong method as I'm not returning it as an array. Can someone hint me the right direction. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the in-built function [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
In [59]: lis=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
In [61]: filter(lambda x:x>=3,lis)  #return only those values which are >=3
Out[61]: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thank you! just the method I was looking for.
I still don't understand the use of lambda, so I'll go read up on it now.

Comment: @user1692517 Reading up on `lambda` is good but I prefer the list comprehension in this situation, it's also easy to understand.

Answer (score 7):

Use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[i for i in a if i>x]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def threshold(a, x):
    return [i for i in a if i > x]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def threshold(a,x):
    vals = []
    for i in a:
        if i >= x: vals.append(i)
    return vals
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the homework problem is to actually implement a filter function. Not just use the built in one.

```
def custom_filter(a,x):
    result = []
    for i in a:
        if i >= x:
            result.append(i)
    return result
```